# Best way to load configuration in Perl?

Tags: perl, configuration-files

I want to write an input file for my Perl script.
This file contains configuration for my program.

The input is in Perl format:

```
my $var1 = "/home/moon";
my $var2 = 123;
my $var3 = "output.log";
...
```

My problem is that I don't know how to load this configuration file in this format.
 Can anyone help?

Comment: what? what are you asking? explain :) do you want to run the program `/home/moon` with the parameters `123` and `output.log`?

Comment: It sounds like you want to load configuration. **Do not** put your configuration in a `.pl` file. Use a module for configuration, or roll your own. Load a data structure. Use a format like JSON or YAML, but never load a file that throws variables in your namespace. It will come and haunt you and 10 years later you won't know how to get rid of the stuff. Believe me, I know. :-D

Comment: It seems that you might be interested in [`Getopt::Long`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html).

Comment: guys, why so many downvotes? OP ask about help and good practice, but you downvote such a good question

Comment: Please don't do this. Please put your configuration in a (non-Perl) config file. Your users (and the future maintainers of this code) will appreciate it.

Answer (score 8):

Use '[do](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/do.html)' with the name of the file you wish to source as an argument. The peldoc page even has an example of reading a file of configuration variables.

Note that in order to have access to variables in the calling script you will need to declare them using 'our' in both the main program and the config file you are loading with 'do'.

A more convenient way is to make the content of the config file an anonymous hash, and assign that to a variable in the main program. You can then refer to the keys of the hash to obtain the various configuration settings. An example:

Main Program:

```
my $config=do("configfile.pl");
die "Error parsing config file: $@" if $@;
die "Error reading config file: $!" unless defined $config;

print "Log File: $config->{logfile}\n";
```

configfile.pl

```
{
    logfile => '/home/me/log.txt',
    someParam => 1234,
    someFile => '/home/me/some/file',
}
```

Another thing to be aware of is that loading such a security file can be a security risk. The user can place anything they want inside the file and it will be executed as perl statements! This is particularly nasty if the process loading the file is running under a user other than the one that owns the file - for example, if it will run as root.

There are plenty of modules on cpan offering better solutions for config files, such as [Config::General](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Config-General/General.pm) or Config::Simple. But just using 'do' is OK for a quick hack.

Comment: I don't think `do`'s variables affect the parent process

Comment: Mentioning `do` with hashref could be useful. `{var1 => 1, var2 => 2, ..}`

Comment: +1 for 'But just using 'do' is OK for a quick hack.'

Comment: How exactly do I extract the values from the config file?

Comment: @undroid by dereferencing the `$config` variable, eg. `$config->{logfile}` - see last line of example program

Comment: Quick and easy, but be aware that it is the same as eval `cat config.pl` which will execute code!  Maybe not a secure way to go. See Data::Undump for an actual PPI parser.

Answer (score 1):

Just a thought, but how about Data::Dumper and require?

This Dumps config to console:

```
$ perl -le 'use Data::Dumper;
            $config = { var1 => "/home/moon",
                        var2 => 123,
                        var3 => "output.log",
            };
            print Data::Dumper->Dump([$config],["config"]);'

___output___

$config = {
            'var3' => 'output.log',
            'var1' => '/home/moon',
            'var2' => 123
          };
```

Redirect output to "config.txt" file using ">>", for example, then "require" it in a new file:

```
$ perl -MData::Dumper -le 'require "config.txt"; print Dumper($config);' 
$VAR1 = {
          'var3' => 'output.log',
          'var1' => '/home/moon',
          'var2' => 123
        };
```

...restored variables can be called by their key:

```
$ perl -MData::Dumper -le 'require "config.txt"; print "var1: ", $config->{var1};' 
___output___
var1: /home/moon
```

Just a thought...